# group by child entity in laravel 5 with eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this tables (simplified):

```
products:
    id,
    model_id,
    color

models:
   id,
   name
```

And I want to know how many products do i have of each model and each color, in sql I can do it this way:

```
SELECT models.name, count(*) 
FROM models
INNER JOIN products ON (models.id = products.model_id)
group by products.color, products.model_id
```

But I can't doit with eloquent, this is my code:

```
Model::with('products','products.model')->groupBy('products.color')->groupBy('products.model')->get();
```

throws this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.color' in 'group statement'
```

It's like eloquent does not knows the relationship model with products, what i'm missing?

Update: Moein sends me in the rigth direction, i can solve it by doing this:

```
Model::join('products', 'models.id', '=', 'products.model_id')
                ->selectRaw('products.*, count(*)')
                ->groupBy('products.color')
                ->groupBy('products.modelo_id')
                -> get();
```

Comment: You have to make a join first, Replace "with" with "join" and you are done ( `join('products', 'id', '=', 'product_id')` )

Comment: It's near to work for me, i think it's return the correct products, but how can i add a count column in order to know how many products do i have of any model and color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Moein sends me in the rigth direction, i can solve it by doing this:

```
Model::join('products', 'models.id', '=', 'products.model_id')
            ->selectRaw('products.*, count(*)')
            ->groupBy('products.color')
            ->groupBy('products.modelo_id')
            -> get();
```